# ASCII folding in user search

Tags: feature-request, search, users

When I search for myself in SO User search, I cannot find myself if I don't input the accent in my first name.

[image]

If I input my name with the correct accent, it works fine.

[image]

Could the underlying search treat Unicode characters which are not part of the "Basic Latin" block as their ASCII equivalent?

Comment: Given that not all names here are Latin-character set based, this isn't as simple as all that. What about the Cyrillic, Greek, Armenian, Arabic, Japanese, Chinese, Vietnamese, Tamil, Hebrew, Korean, Devanagari, Burmese and other writing systems that all are in use in names today? Not to mention our Japanese and Russian Stackoverflow sister sites.

Comment: @MartijnPieters A fix that might work for all of those, is to allow people to set a romanized alias of their name, (I've seen this used on other sites). Something like that could also be used in OP's case. Then that alias could be used when searching for a user.

Comment: That has several issues still: there are multiple different romanisations for a given non-Latin name, it requires the users to actually fill this out, it has no use on non-Latin sites such as the Japanese or the Russian sites, and the extra effort to implement that doesn't make sense on sites that are question centric (this isn't a social network).

Comment: Maybe I'm not thinking globally enough, but wouldn't it still be a benefit if at least Latin-compatible names were automatically handled like this? Someone looking for a non-Latin name wouldn't even try to search with a Latin version, but someone might naturally try the same with a name that is almost entirely ASCII compliant (disclaimer: my real name is András Deák). Would it lead to too much load/work to implement something like this? (cc @Martijn)

Comment: Last time I had to do something like this I applied Unicode NFKD normalization to the strings and dropped every combining character from the result and used that for index/search; the result seemed to work fine.

Comment: FWIW: [Lucene's ASCIIFoldingFilter](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/e2521b2a8baabdaf43b92192588f51e042d21e97/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/ASCIIFoldingFilter.java)

Comment: @JornVernee I can already see the meta post "Why does the user search show me all these completely unrelated accounts?".

Comment: I think that's the correct behaviour actually. We've been trained to expect to find "andré" when searching for "andre" because the majority of programs are bad at handling accents, but really "é" is just not the same letter as "e". Or else we are talking about fuzzy matching, which maybe could return "andrea", etc. too but that's a different issue.

Comment: The problem isn't programs being bad at handling accents, it's *keyboards*. Quick: type é on a US keyboard. You had to look up the Unicode codepoint, didn't you? (So that you could type the Alt+keypad code). Or you had to bring up the Character Map and copy-and-paste. People who know perfectly well that `e` is not the same character as `é` may still type "Aurelien" instead of "Aurélien" because they're stuck with the US keyboard attached to this unfamiliar computer, **and they expect that the software will figure it out**. IMHO, matching `é` when searching for `e` is the *right* thing to do.

Comment: @rmunn Easily. On Mac :)

Comment: Heh. I should have specified "on a Windows system", because I typed é very easily on Linux using the great [Compose key feature](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/i18n/compose/en_US.UTF-8.html). Compose + e + apostrophe = é. It's only on Windows that this is challenging, but Windows is about 85% of the desktop OS market, so that's still millions of users who will have trouble typing any characters that aren't on their specific keyboards.

Comment: "meh, 128 characters is more than enough for all the needs there will ever be" - someone who's actions had a great deal more side effects than expected, circa 1990

Comment: @rmunn if you use the international layout w dead keys, Alt Gr + letter to get its tilded variant.

Comment: @rmunn On windows I can uses apostrophe + e to get é, and my keyboard is set to 'United States-International'. I don't have a é key on my keyboard either. I assumed it worked like that for everyone else, just that some people don't know about that feature.

Comment: @Idolon I think you meant "emacs" there. ;P

Answer (score -1):

> Could the underlying search treat Unicode characters which are not part of the "Basic Latin" block as their ASCII equivalent?

While understandably an issue of convenience, the problem is when doing such transformations, you are making assumptions about what is considered "equivalent", and that can sometimes be a matter of perspective. But whose perspective? Take a look at the various options here:

http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/tags/latest/common/transforms/

Starting with the first file, [Amharic-Latin-BGN.xml](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/tags/latest/common/transforms/Amharic-Latin-BGN.xml), we can see examples that translate directly to ASCII, such as:

> ዩ → yu ; # ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE YU

but then others that don't, such as:

> ኴ → kwē ; # ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE KWEE

This second example still has a [Latin Small Letter E with Macron](https://unicode-table.com/en/0113/) that needs deaccentification (yes, that is a word, as of this writing).

Given that the existing search seems to satisfy the vast majority of cases, it probably makes the most sense to keep it but add another search option. For this there are probably two options:

1. Copy the names to a second index. This will take up more space, but is somewhat simple and yields a fast search. Keep the current search text field and just add a check-box (or something along those lines) to indicate that the search is to use the second index. There are two sub-options here:

   1. (preferred) Use same data but with an accent insensitive Collation. In SQL Server terms (even though this might not be implemented in SQL Server), if the current index is using `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS_SC`, then this new index (on a non-persisted computed column) would use `Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_KS_WS_SC`. Check-box is labeled: "Ignore Accents / Diacritics".
   2. Transform the data as it is being placed into the second index (or new column that is indexed) according to the "official" Unicode® specifications.

      http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/tags/latest/common/transforms/Latin-ASCII.xml

      And maybe also:

      http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/tags/latest/common/transforms/Any-Accents.xml

      Similar to original request, but does not change exist functionality and uses established / reliable transformation rules (unlike Lucene's ASCIIFolding that someone suggested). Check-box is labeled: "Ignore everything".
2. Use [International Components for Unicode (ICU)](http://site.icu-project.org/) to perform the search. This is a full implementation of the Unicode Standard and is highly flexible. The idea here would be to have a link for "Advanced Search" next to the search text field that displays additional options for tailoring how the search should be performed. This has the benefits of a) not needing to copy the data to a second index, and b) not making any assumptions and being able to do pretty much anything. However, it does have the drawback of not performing so super greatly given that the data cannot be indexed since there is no way to determine the sort keys until the user has configured the sort options (hence the flexibility and less-than-ideal performance). Also, there is no .NET port of this; it officially comes in C/C++ and Java. Of course, on their [Related ICU Projects](http://site.icu-project.org/related) page, there is a link to an R based project for this, [stringi](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=stringi), which might could allow for using with SQL Server as it now has the ability to query R directly (just a thought).

   Demos located at:

   - http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/collation.html
   - http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?_=en_US&d_=en&x=col&collation=search